# JFrame/Panel stops instanciation/Constructor callup

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

This is a bug that I tracked down yesterday and since then having a hard time to actually describe it.

The bug itself starts in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LogManager();
        new ConfigManager();
        new Rendering();
        new ScriptManager();
        new FileManager();
        new SleepManager(System.currentTimeMillis()); <-- Here it is as if the JVM just stops reading code
```

Since I work with eclipse I used breakpoints to locate the problematic line. And it actually reaches that last line(`new SleepManager`) but the method breakpoint at the SleepManager constructor is never reached:

```
public SleepManager(long t) {
        lastCheck = t;
```

There is only that one constructor in the class. And in addition there is no exception whatsoever.
But eventually I managed to narrow it down to my JFramework in the Rendering Class:

```
public class Rendering extends JPanel implements Runnable {
   private static final Log LOG = new Log(Rendering.class.getSimpleName());
   private static GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0];

   public Rendering() {

        //define basics
        systemFullScreen_width = device.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        systemFullScreen_height = device.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
        width = (systemFullScreen_width > 0 ? systemFullScreen_width : width);
        height = (systemFullScreen_height > 0 ? systemFullScreen_height : height);

        //crate framework
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.addWindowListener(new FrameClose());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.5f));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle(" Monitor ");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, Collections.<AWTKeyStroke> emptySet()); //TODO remove if not needed
        panel = this;
        panel.setSize(width, height);
        panel.setBackground(new Color(0.4f,0.4f,0.4f,0.9f));

    --> frame.add(panel, 0); //here i suspect the error

        panel.revalidate();
        panel.setVisible(true);

        //start rendering
        this.start();

        //frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true); //TODO enable at the end
        
        //set input listeners
        frame.addKeyListener(input);
        frame.addMouseListener(input);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(input);
        frame.addMouseWheelListener(input);
        LOG.info("Rendering started!");
    }
```

Ok so what I actually did accomplish in that method *(since it worked when I wrote it and the transparent grey background is still working/visible)* is that I try to create a half-transparent semi-fullscreen grey background to later render my own GUI element on it aka Graphics2D. Had rough time working around the fullscreen/transparency/lightweight container problem but still open for better solutions if someone has them.

So the marked line(`frame.add(panel, 0);`) seems to be the problem because it works when I remove the line *(simple as that)* and it seems to be the only line that does so.

The `panel.revalidate();` was my first idea it did not help, jet i decided to keep it anyway.

Can't wrap my head around why that one line that was already done by runtime should stop another method, 200 lines beneath from being called? Any ideas?

---

**Edit1:**
Thanks to Matt who pointed out that these code lines are indeed somehow important to the subject:

```
   public void render(Graphics2D g2d){
        while(isRunning){
            renderGUI(g2d); //this method does nothing jet its empty
        }
        frame.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        render((Graphics2D) g);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isRunning){
            try{
                frame.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }catch(Exception e){
                LOG.error(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit2:**

What actually led me to the solution: Matt mentioned "*EDT*" what I didn't knew so I googled it and learn what the ***Event Dispatch Thread*** is. So now I knew, before `this.start` to start the thread gets called, the EDT actually at some point calls the `paintComponent` method first and enters this ugly child-code doubleloop-ception that I totally overlooked. Honestly... Shame on me. Thx Matt.

Comment: You'll need to create a minimal reproducible example. You really shouldn't be doing GUI work on the main thread. You also shouldn't be doing all this work in the constructors. You should create the object, then build the gui on the edt. You also have a `this.start()` which seems to imply threads. Are you running out of memory? What does your paintComponent method look like?

Comment: @matt Well yea you're right but the program will only be for myself and it is in its early stage so i figured i put the stuff into main for now. Also right the Rendering class implements Runnable. Nop memory is plenty. And for the paintComponent() method just the super.paintComponent and everything i would be rendering later but i did not include it in my post since it would be to much to read and when i take the this.start line out the problem is still existent so it would not be the reason for my bug

Comment: It's just super.paintComponent, and "and everything i would be rendering later ". So it isn't just super.paintComponent? When you add your panel to the jframe, it *should* get layed out and painted on the EDT, so if a related method did something "weird" then you could have an issue. Something weird like, System.exit or Some sort of recursive object construction. etc.